# My Apache (mod_wsgi) Django app only lists the files instead of the actually running website/application

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

My Apache (mod_wsgi) Django app only lists the files of my website/project instead of the actual running website/application. My guess is that it's mod_wsgi that is the culprit but I'm not really sure. What are some of the causes of this?

Comment: Would have been helpful to post the Apache configuration, rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put your Django site code in a directory Apache can serve up. Right now if I knew the actual site host name, I could get down your Django settings file and get access to your database password information.

Anyway, ensure you have gone and set up a basic WSGI hello world program before you attempt to get Django working under mod_wsgi. In doing this, ensure you use the official mod_wsgi documentation and not some arbitrary persons blog post. As such, go read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

Also go watch the video presentation at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations

as it steps you through basic configuration as well as what to do for Django. It covers all the basic things that people do wrong.

If you still can't get it to work, then heed the comments in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Asking_Your_Questions

about useful information you should supply to any forum to help people solve your problem.

Comment: Ah, okay. I will go through all of that first, then try again. I wish I would of have those links in the beginning before heading down this "rabbit hole". :) Thank you much! j.

Comment: Hard to understand how you could miss it if you had gone to the official mod_wsgi site in the first place. :-)